# Non uniqueness of Hahn Banach extension...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find a measure space $(X, \mu)$ and a subspace $Y$ of $L^1(\mu)$ and a bounded linear functional $f$ on $Y$ with norm $1$ such that $f$ has two distinct extensions each with norm $1$ to all of $L^1(\mu)$.

I'd hope the space was $[0,1]$, the subspace was something like $L^2$ or $C[0,1]$, but what would the functional be? Am I on the right track?

Comment: The subspace must not be dense. If it is dense, a continuous extension is necessarily unique.

Comment: Maybe I'm being naive, but what is a canonical non dense subset of $L^1[0,1]$?

Comment: Any finite-dimensional proper subspace would qualify, I guess. There's no particular non-dense subspace that is somehow distinguished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try letting $X$ be just two points, with $\mu$ counting measure. Let $Y$ consist of the functions vanishing on one of the two points of $X$.

**Edit:** Here is (much) more detail. Put $X=\{1,2\}$ to be specific. You can think of a function $x\colon X\to\mathbb{C}$ as a pair $x=(x_1,x_2)$, where we write $x_j$ instead of $x(j)$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$. Then $\int x\,d\mu=x_1+x_2$, and in particular $\|x\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$. Now let $Y=\{(x_1,0)\colon x_1\in\mathbb{C}\}$, and define $f(x_1,0)=x_1$. The most general linear extension of $f$ to all of $L^1(\mu)$ can be written $f_a(x_1,x_2)=x_1+ax_2$, where $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Now you need to do *some* work yourself, so I leave it to you to compute $\|f\|$ and $\|f_a\|$.

Comment: So, is it true that the integral of all such functions under the counting measure is either 0 or 1? If so, can we take our functional to send $f$ to it's integral? I'm a little confused how this extends in more than one way.

Comment: No, the integral can take any complex value. You are mixing up the measure and the integral somehow. I provided a lot more detail in the answer now.

Comment: I have one more question before I compute the norms. What is the intuition behind taking the integral to be the sum of the coordinates?

Comment: On a finite measure space, *every* function is a simple function. In this case (sticking with the notation from the answer), $x=x_1\chi_{\{1\}}+x_2\chi_{\{2\}}$, so the definition of the integral of a simple function yields $\int x\,d\mu=x_1\mu(\{1\})+x_2\mu(\{2\})=x_1+x_2$. (Intuitively, the integral is a generalized sum – but in this case, there is nothing “generalized” about it – it *is* a sum.)